# exact working of hough transform in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

Can anyone guide me how the function 'hough transform' works in matlab?? The problem is that i have an image containing two straight rectangles and one rectangle is tilted at some angle. According to me after applying hough transform;  i should get a line structure of 1X6 but i am getting a structure of 1x14. Can anyone help me? I have also uploaded the images:

[image: two straight rectangles, one tilted rectangle]

[image: hough transform applied]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict Hough Transform to give a structure of 1x6.It doesn't produce stabile results.It also doesn't work well when looking further ahead on curved roads. I should not acquire 1x6 structure from each frame.Instead, I should take all returned line segments and use some logic to determine the lane markings.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your image actually looks slightly blurred. I don't know if it actually is , but if so, you need to run an edge detection algorithm, so your hough transform does not detect the blurred part of the line.

Second of all, you need to reduce the number of detected lines, simply by taking out any lines which does not have enough points going through it. This can be done by thresholding the H variable in [H,t,r]=hough(image).

Additional Sources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform
http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/hough.html